# plot lines using qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot multiple lines on the sample plot using qplot in the ggplot2 package.
But I'm having some problem with it.

Using the old plot, and lines function I would do something like

```
m<-cbind(1:4,5:8,-(5:8))
colnames(m)<-c("time","y1","y2")
m<-as.data.frame(m)
> m
  time y1 y2
1    1  5 -5
2    2  6 -6
3    3  7 -7
4    4  8 -8
plot(x=m$time,y=m$y1,type='l',ylim=range(m[,-1]))
lines(x=m$time,y=m$y2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the reshape package to `melt` m:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

m2 <- melt(m, id = "time")
p <- ggplot(m2, aes(x = time, y = value, color = variable))
p + geom_line() + ylab("y")
```

You could rename the columns in the new data.frame to your liking. The trick here is to have a factor that denotes each of the lines you want to plot.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now, I don'r quite understand the aes function, but I wont worry about that for now.

Comment: `qplot(time, value, data = m2, colour = variable, geom = "line") + ylab("y")` is the translation to the `qplot` syntax.

Comment: The online docs (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) have a wealth of examples, including how to set up the aes statement.